# debug.keystore does not exist

Tags: java, android, google-maps, cmd, md5

I'm trying to generate an MD5 fingerprint but the problem is that everytime i try typing in the whole code, it says debug.keystore does not exist. I've seem multiple different threads on the same thing but none of them seemed to really help my issue.

What i type in is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>keytool -v -list -alias
androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Can sombody please help me debug this problem? thank you.

Comment: You can use Eclipse ADT to create a new Debug Keystore and then make it use this one instead of the one created by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse you can find the location of your debug keystore with:

Window > Preferences> Android > Click the triangle on left of "Android"to open the sub menu >  Build

This will tell you location of your debug keystore and let you set a custom debug keystore.

Comment: so is that what i type into command prompt? instead of all the other stuff?

Comment: C:\Users\Kwesi\.android\debug.keystore  This is the address that i have in my preferences.

Comment: You will still need the to write in the command shell but instead of just having -keystore debug.keystore you need to put the full path to you keystore.

Comment: If you use Eclipse choosing Window > Preferences etc as above it will tell you the path. You can also just try searching your file system.  I found that I needed to enclose my path in inverted commas.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunatelly there is a new Eclipse plugin for that.

- Press `Help > Install New Software`.
- Press `Add`.
- Type a name for your tool, I named it keytool.
- For the location paste the following link:
  `http://keytool.sourceforge.net/update`

Then check the Keytool and press Next and then Install

It will ask you if you trust this certificate. Press Ok.

When it is installed eclipse will restart and then you will see a new button on your toolbar, called Keytool (it will have a key icon). Press it, fill in your name, password etc. and it will give you your md5 Fingerprint. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed the development environment, there is no virtual device defined yet. If there are no virtual devices created, it will not build this debug.keystore file. So,  first create your virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "c:\documents and 
settings\ndotdes65.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Try Like this...

place the proper path for debug.keystore....

Hope it will work..!